# C# event from a class in a custom usercontrol never fires

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have a class that has an event that's suppose to fire everytime one of it's property changes.

```
    public event EventHandler StructureChanged;
    protected virtual void NotifyStructureChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (StructureChanged != null)
        {
            StructureChanged(this, e);
        }
    }
```

I include `NotifyStructureChanged(new EventArgs());` in my set statement in my properties.
whenever it calls the method the `StructureChanged`is always null.  My class is a private member in a custom usercontrol and the class event is registered in the constructor of the usercontrol like so

`_pt.StructureChanged += _pt_StructureChanged;`

and handled here

```
    void _pt_StructureChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateControl();
    }
```

What I have so far is a custom class with an event that's a private member of a custom user control.  I register my class event in the custom usercontrol.  Whenever the class property changes, I update my control to reflect the changes in the class.

What am I doing wrong here?  I have a button on my usercontrol and am able to register that event, why can't I register my class event?

Comment: As a side note, you need to do `StructureChanged handler = StructureChanged;` and check `handler` for `null`. Otherwise there is a race condition which could cause a `NullReferenceException` in a multi-threaded situation.

Answer (score 0):

If `StructureChanged` is `null` than you attach event handler *after* event was fired (or you are detaching handler somewhere).

Also don't pass `EventArgs` - its just useless dummy parameter.

```
public event EventHandler StructureChanged;

protected virtual void OnStructureChanged()
{
    if (StructureChanged != null)        
        StructureChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);        
}
```

And call this method in setter:

```
public Foo Bar
{
    get { return _bar; }
    set {
       if (_bar == value)
          return;

       _bar = value;
       OnStructureChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: I do call the `OnStructureChanged()` method in the setter when in the method the StructureChanged field is always null.  I don't explicitly detach the handler anywhere in my code.  This user control is graphical with buttons,textbox and is used in a winform.

Comment: @user3421997 then you definitely raise event *before* handler is attached. It would be nice to see your setter, and participants of this logic. Who raises event? When? Who subscribes? When?

Comment: this is my logic.  I have a PtClass with the StructureChanged event.  that is a private field of a custom usercontrol.  The usercontrol subscribes to the StructureChanged event in it's constructor.  The usercontrol will be hosted on a winform.  When the winform loads it creates a PtClass object which gets assigned to the usercontrol.